# How to fix undefined identifier error with snmp

Tags: snmp

I try to use HOST-RESOURCES-MIB with snmptranslate, but it shows following error:

```
Did not find 'hrMIBAdminInfo' in module HOST-RESOURCES-MIB (/home_ldap/kbuscsei/mibsnew2//HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES.txt)
Unlinked OID in HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES: hostResourcesTypesModule ::= { hrMIBAdminInfo 4 }
Undefined identifier: hrMIBAdminInfo near line 7 of /home_ldap/kbuscsei/mibsnew2//HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES.txt
Cannot adopt OID in HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES: hostResourcesTypesModule ::= { hrMIBAdminInfo 4 }
```

That identifier is diffined in HOST-RESOURCES-MIB at line 108

```
hrMIBAdminInfo  OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { host 7 }
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It can only be a bug of the `snmptranslate` utility you use, as that `HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES` is part of the standards.

Most MIB document parsers should pick up the definition from line 107 and do not report any error, but buggy ones can simply fail to work properly in such typical scenarios.

I am not sure which `snmptranslate` utility you are using, but there are tons of alternatives that are compliant to the standards.

Comment: I use version 5.7.3. I'll give a try on a other box over the weekend, where everything is updated.

Comment: It has ended up, some of the extensions were .mib some were .txt.
since all have been renamed to .txt all works fine.